# Compute Taylor series at $x = 0$ of $e^{1-\cos{x}}$ in summation notation?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am doing an exercise from textbook which asks to compute Taylor series at  $x = 0$ of $e^{1-\cos{x}}$ in summation notation?

My intuition was to expand function $e^x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and $\cos{x} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ at ${x = 0}$, so I got the result: 
$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1 - \sum^{\infty}_{t=0}(-1)^t\frac{x^{2t}}{(2t)!}}{k!}$.

The result is a form of 2 summations, thus I am not too sure whether it is correct. Could anyone please help to verify or give some comments?

Thanks for VVejalla's comment, the double summation result I got should be: $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(1 - \sum^{\infty}_{t=0}(-1)^t\frac{x^{2t}}{(2t)!})^k}{k!}$

Comment: What you have is not a power series, let alone a Taylor series, because it is not of the form $\sum_n a_nx^n$

Comment: It should be $$e^{1-\cos(x)}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(1-\cos(x))^k}{k!}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(1-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!})^k}{k!}$$ but even then, it is not a power series in $x$

Comment: By brute force you can get a few terms.  This might give you an idea what the general term looks like.

Comment: Except for sign, the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ is $a(n)/(2n)!$ where a(n) is [OEIS sequence A260884](https://oeis.org/A260884).  There doesn't seem to be a closed form.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Good point, The expression I wrote down is not the summation of polynomial terms and not a Taylor series at all.

Comment: @VVejalla Thanks for the correction, my expression is missing the power term in the outside summation.

Comment: You may get an expression for the coefficients using complete Bell polynomials, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) =e^{1-\cos x} $ so that $$f'(x) =f(x) \sin x\tag{1}$$ Let us assume that $f(x) $ can be represented as a power series in terms of even powers of $x$ (because $f$ is even) so that $$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{2n}\tag{2}$$ Differentiating term by term we get $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2na_nx^{2n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{2n+1}$$ Putting the series for $f'$ and $f$ in $(1)$ we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{2n}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ Cancelling $x$ from both sides we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{2n}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$ Comparing coefficients of $x^{2n}$ on both sides we get $$2(n+1)a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{a_k}{(2n-2k+1)!}$$ Starting with $a_0=1$ (as $f(0)=1$) we get $$2a_1=\frac{a_0}{1!}$$ so that $a_1=1/2$. Similarly $$4a_2=-\frac{a_0}{3!}+\frac{a_1}{1!}$$ ie $a_2=1/12$ and $$6a_3=\frac{a_0}{5!}-\frac{a_1}{3!}+a_2$$ ie $a_3=1/720$.

Thus $$f(x) =1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\dots$$

Comment: why do you assume only even power terms in $f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n x^{2n}$ ?

Comment: @user2262504: because $f$ is even function. You can prove that if $f$ is even function then the coefficients of odd powers of $x$ in its Taylor series around $0$ are zero. This follows from $f(x) =f(-x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the earlier question, another question about $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}2(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{2n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nx^{2n} . \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$, how do you get this, could you please show more detailed steps?

Comment: @user2262504: Differentiate the series for $f(x) $ to get $$f'(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2na_nx^{2n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{2n+1}$$ and $$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and then from the product we cancel the factor $x$ on both sides.

Comment: @user2262504: I have also updated my answer with details because some people may not read all the comments.

Comment: Thanks for extra information, it is really helpful. As for the step of comparing coefficient of $x^{2n}$. I guess that you loop through all kth term of first summation multiply (n-k)th term of second summation. ($0 \leq k \leq n$) Am I correct to understand in this way?

Comment: @user2262504: a term of $x^{2n}$ can come only by multiplying term $x^{2k}$ from one series and $x^{2n-2k}$ from another series for $0\leq k\leq n$. I think you also want to say the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107990/discussion-between-user2262504-and-paramanand-singh).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite difficult but I think that I found something which is a least amazing.

Consider the expansion of
$$e^{1-\cosh (y)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(2n)!} \,y^{2n}$$ The first $a_n$'s make the sequence
$$\{1,-1,2,-1,-43,254,4157,-70981,-1310398,40933619,1087746617\}$$ which is sequence [$A260884$ in OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+-1%2C+2%2C+-1%2C+-43%2C+254%2C+4157%2C+-70981%2C+-1310398%2C+40933619&sort=&language=&go=Search). According to the documentation, they are given by
$$a_n=\sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \text{BellY}[2 n,k,\left[\text{Range}[2 n] \bmod 2\right]-1]\qquad \text{with} \qquad a_0=1$$

Now, make $y=i\,x$ to make
$$e^{1-\cosh (y)-1}=e^{1-\cos (x)}$$

Comment: It should not be too hard to find the derivatives of $e^{f(x)}$, no? Your method is probably faster though :)

Comment: An other approach is via obtaining the moments via the cumulants

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of computing the moments from the cumulants, which is the inverse problem as the one usually encountered.

Consider a (analytic) function $K(x)$ with $K(0)=0$

\begin{align}
M(x) &:=e^{K(x)}=\exp{\sum_{n=1} \kappa_n \frac{x^n}{n!} } \\
     &:= \sum_{n=0} \mu_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align}

with $\mu_0 =1$. Then one has the following recursion

$$
\mu_{n}=\kappa_{n}+\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1\\
m-1
\end{array}\right)\kappa_{m}\mu_{n-m}
$$

Indeed the identity holds with greater generality at the level of formal power series. In our case $K(x) = 1- \cos(x)$ so $\kappa_{2n} = -(-1)^n$ and $\kappa_{2n+1}=0$. Of course one also has that $\mu_{2n+1}=0$.

With the above formula one gets, for the first few non-zero coefficients

$$
\mu_n = (1, 2, 1, -43, -254, 4157, 70981, -1310398, -40933619, 1087746617,\ldots)
$$

which agrees with Claude Leibovici's results (but here we have the correct signs).

Answer (score 0):

You can express the general coefficient in terms of the complete Bell polynomials $B_n$ in the following manner:
\begin{align*}
\exp (1 - \cos x) & = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{x^{2n} }}{{(2n)!}}} } \right) \\ &= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}B_n \!\left( {\frac{{1!}}{{2!}}, \ldots ,( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{n!}}{{(2n)!}}} \right)x^{2n} } .
\end{align*}
An explicit, though somewhat complicated, formula is as follows:
$$
B_n \!\left( {\frac{{1!}}{{2!}}, \ldots ,( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{n!}}{{(2n)!}}} \right) \\ = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{\substack{ j_1  + j_2  +  \cdots  + j_{n - k + 1}  = k \\ j_1  + 2j_2  +  \cdots  + (n - k + 1)j_{n - k + 1}  = n \\ j_1 ,j_2 , \ldots ,j_{n - k + 1}  \in \mathbb{Z}_{ \ge 0} }} {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + k} n!}}{{j_1 !j_2 ! \cdots j_{n - k + 1} !}}\prod\limits_{m = 1}^{n - k + 1} {\frac{1}{{(2m)!^{j_m } }}} } } .
$$

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. I don't know Bell polynomials. Can you provide some links for me to learn Bell polynomials and allow me towards fully understand your answer?

Comment: You may start with the corresponding Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials

Answer (score 0):

The higher order derivatives of $f(x)=\exp(1-\cos(x))$ have a nice structure.
$$
  \begin{align}
  f'(x) &= f(x)\sin(x) \nonumber\\
  f''(x) &= f'(x)\sin(x) + f(x)\cos(x) \nonumber\\
  f^{(3)}(x) &= f''(x)\sin(x) + 2f'\cos(x) - f(x)\sin(x) \nonumber\\
  f^{(4)}(x) &= f^{(3)}(x)\sin(x) + 3f''(x)\cos(x) - 3f'(x)\sin x - f(x)\cos(x) \nonumber\\
  f^{(5)} &= f^{(4)}\sin + 4f^{(3)}\cos - 6f''\sin - 4f'\cos + f\sin \nonumber\\
  \vdots
  \end{align}
$$
All odd-order derivatives are 0 at $x=0$.  You can see that the coefficients on the right hand side
are the binomial coefficients (with periodic signs $+,+,-,-$).  So the equation for the $2n$th order 
derivative of $f$ at 0 is:
$$
  f^{(2n)}(0) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{2i+1} f^{(2n-1-2i)}(0)(-1)^i.
$$
The values for $n=0,1,\dots 10$ are
$$
1, 1, 2, 1, -43, -254, 4157, 70981, -1310398, -40933619, 1087746617.
$$